# Как правильно записать файл в БД

Tags: база-данных, структуры

Добрый день. Есть файл со структурой вида:

```
$$    
0002:SOMEDATA20DIG:00129954:0016:82:19:161102:2
    0000:DATWITH12DIG:00:0000:00+000000+0000000+0000000000
    Пропуск сотни строк
    1012:DATWITH12DIG:45:0000:00+000000+0000000+0000000000
    1100:DATWITH12DIG:00:0000:00+000000+0000000+0000000000
    1101:DATWITH12DIG:65:0500:00+000068+0000069+0015333800
    1102:DATWITH12DIG:61:0000:00+000000+0000000+0000000000
    1103:DATWITH12DIG:51:0000:00+000000+0000000+0000000000
    1104:DATWITH12DIG:51:0000:00+000000+0000000+0000000000
    1105:DATWITH12DIG:51:0000:20+000000+0000000+0000000000
    1109:DATWITH12DIG:01:0000:00+000000+0000000+0000000000
    1201:DATWITH12DIG:27:0000:00+000000+0000000+0000000000
    1401:DATWITH12DIG:05:0500:00+000000+0000000+0000000000
    1801:DATWITH12DIG:05:0500:00+000065+0000065+0020218750
    1901:DATWITH12DIG:45:0000:00+000000+0000000+0000000000
$$
```

Это один элемент, всего таких элементов может быть максимум 800 штук разделяются $$
Каждый занимает фиксированное количество строк 236.
Все номера позиций повторяются как минимум 2 раза. 
Файл я распарcил по + и : и записал в базу из 8 столбцов.
Но возникла проблема, как уникализировать блок данных, чтобы потом привязать данные блока к первой строке `0002:SOMEDATA20DIG:00129954:0016:82:19:161102:2`

При вводе в таблицу использовать еще один столбец к который прописывать какой либо идентификатор?
Или вытянуть все данные в одну строку и записывать каждый элемент в новый солбец(тогда их получился слишком много)?
Может быть еще есть какие либо способы?

Comment: Пересмотрел я ваши вопросы ... вам бы разобраться какое из полей в этих данных что означает и в БД хранить уже с осмысленными названиями и главное, с подабающими типами данных. Незачем хранить числа с ведущими нулями и потом придумывать способы как после сложения добавлять ведущие нули. Если на выходе программы такие ведущие нули потребуются - вот в тот момент их и добавлять. Так будет значительно проще работать. Может еще какие закономерности в данных есть, заслуживающие хранения вообще в отдельных таблицах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас в базе должно быть две таблицы. В одну таблицу Вы записываете данные строк

```
0002:SOMEDATA20DIG:00129954:0016:82:19:161102:2
```

+ отдельным полем некоторый уникальный идентификатор (первичный ключ). Проще и правильнее этот идентификатор сделать через автоинкрементное поле.

Во вторую таблицу записываете данные строк

```
0000:DATWITH12DIG:00:0000:00+000000+0000000+0000000000
```

+ отдельным полем число, идентифицирующее запись в первой таблице. Классическая связь "один ко многим"